# Getting "Backend error. Job aborted" while trying to export a big query table to GCS

Tags: google-bigquery

Since the past couple of weeks I have been continuously getting "Backend error. Job aborted" error while trying to export a big query table to google cloud storage in csv format.

The table has been created using bq select * statement (using allowLargeQueryResult option)

Also the target bucket name doesn't seem to be problematic.

Here's a sample extract.

`Errors:
Backend error. Job aborted.
Job ID: kiwiup.com:kiwi-bigquery:job_mk90xJqtyinbzRqIfWVjM2mHLP0
Start Time: 2:53pm, 8 Aug 2014
End Time: 8:53pm, 8 Aug 2014`

The job is taking almost six hours to complete after which it fails. Previously it used to complete in a couple of minutes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you send a job id of a failed job? Thanks

Comment: edited in the question. Thanks

Comment: Hi Jordan, Still waiting for an answer to this one. It is critical for our data migration activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your export job hit a timeout. We're currently investigating why; the date of your job coincides with a bandwidth issue we were having that should have been resolved. We're currently adding more instrumentation and monitoring so it will be easier to debug in the future.

As a workaround, if you give multiple extraction URI patterns, BigQuery will spin up more workers in parallel. See the "Multiple Wildcard URIs" example [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery#exportingmultiple).

Answer (score 0):

As Jordan said, this coincided with a bandwidth problem. Sorry for the inconvenience.

In some cases, giving multiple wildcard URIs will increase parallelism, but this applies only to fairly large (10's of GB) tables, and can actually decrease parallelism. Multiple wildcard URIs are designed to support Hadoop jobs, not to control parallelism.

Comment: Hi Jason, Here are two more export job Id's which I recently started, which by the looks of it, will fail eventually : kiwiup.com:kiwi-bigquery:job_Nm_P4rBaulRe1qxLVT0Ga5MzWko , kiwiup.com:kiwi-bigquery:job_aCADxll5jVEv1to0rF_C1tAOR5U. We are just going for single wildcard URI. Here's one job which succeeded immediately as the data involved was minimal (a few KB's). We just executed it as  a POC. kiwiup.com:kiwi-bigquery:job_Clor13z6Iwv_l1aFskuQKN3OX94